# Linker issue with default values for constructor parameters

Tags: c++, static, linker, default-value

I am trying to impose some sort of semantic logic for the default values of method (or constructor) parameters. Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Test
{
public:
    static const std::vector<int> staticVector;
    Test (const std::vector<int> &x = Test::staticVector) {}
};

int main ()
{
    Test x;

    return 0;
}
```

Although staticVector is rather redundant, since C++ does not allow NULL to be passed as an instance of std::vector, I wish to avoid making redundant calls to the constructor std::vector(), so I came up with this approach...

Unfortunately, when I try to compile it, the linker throws this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const Test::staticVector" (?staticVector@Test@@2V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@B)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @chris Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the use of a default parameter.  Instead, it's a side-effect of how static variables work in C++.

Having a static object in a C++ class is a two-step process.  First, you have to declare the static object, which you've done, but then you have to actually define it somewhere so C++ knows which translation unit should contain the one definition of that static object.  You can do this by writing

```
const std::vector<int> Test::staticVector;
```

somewhere in your C++ source file outside of the class.  This tells C++ that your source file contains the definition of this object, which should resolve the linker error.

If you have several different source files and not just one, then you should put this line in the source file for the `Test` class rather than in the header.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, yes, I knew I was forgetting something :) Thank you very much. Just curious, why is it always necessary to declare it outside the class? It seems a bit odd...

Comment: @MihaiTodor- You have to declare it outside the class so that the compiler and linker know which object file actually contains the definition of the static object.  That way, the linker can resolve references to the static object to a single entity.

Comment: Now I understand the reasoning. Thank you very much for the detailed explanations!

Comment: The precise term is *define*. Inside the class definition you *declare* the members, but static data members must be *defined* outside of the class definition if they are *odr-used*.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the static member, but not defined it. After the class you need something like:

```
 const std::vector<int> Test::staticVector;
```

You may want to initialise it with some value depending on what you'rre really planning on doing with it.